# Стили, для дерево категорий MySQL и рекурсивная функция PHP

Tags: php, css

В интернете нашел: дерево категорий MySQL и рекурсивная функция PHP. 
Сделал так же, но у меня весь список в ряд по вертикале. 
rfr Как настроить стили для этого скрипта? И сделать аккордеон для него, чтобы нажать на родительский список, открывалcя дочерний. И закрывались предыдущие открытые дочерние списки.

```
// подключаемся к базе данных
// делаем выборку из таблицы категорий
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT `id`, `parent_id`, `name` FROM `category`"); 

$cats = array(); // тут будет наш массив с категориями каталога
// в цикле формируем нужный нам массив
  while($cat =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $cats[$cat['parent_id']][] =  $cat;
// далее наша главная, рекурсивная функция, которая сформирует дерево категорий
function create_tree ($cats,$parent_id){
  if(is_array($cats) and  isset($cats[$parent_id])){
    $tree = '<ul>';
    foreach($cats[$parent_id] as $cat){
       $tree .= "<li><a href='view_cat.php?cat=".$cat['id']."'>".$cat['name']."</a>";
       $tree .=  create_tree ($cats,$cat['id']);
       $tree .= '</li>';         
    }
    $tree .= '</ul>';
  } 
  else return null;          
return $tree;        
} 

// вызываем функцию и строим дерево
echo create_tree ($cats, 0);
```

К примеру вот такой стиль
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не совсем понятно в чём проблема настроить для него стили, могли бы вы описать проблему более детально?

Comment: @webDev_ вот я исправил. Да мне надо как то для него стили прописать. Начинал но что то без результат но. Пример выложил тоже. И аккордеон для него тоже как то надо прописать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(function(){subList = function() {
 var e = document.querySelectorAll('.sublist');
 for (var i=0;i<e.length;i++) {
  var ee = e[i].querySelectorAll('span');
  for (var ii=0;ii<ee.length;ii++) {
   if (e[i].className.match(/counter/)) {
    var c = document.createElement('i');
    c.innerText=ee[ii].parentNode.querySelector('ul').children.length;
    ee[ii].appendChild(c);
   }
   ee[ii].addEventListener('click',(function(e,p){return function(){
    if (!e.className) {
     var el = e.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.show');
     if (el.length) {
      for (var i=0;i<el.length;i++) {
       el[i].className = '';
       if (i==el.length-1) {
        e.className = 'show';
       }
      }
     }else{
      e.className = 'show';
     }
    }else{
     e.className = '';
    }
   }})(ee[ii].parentNode,e[i]),false);
  }
 }
}})();
window.onload = function(){subList()};
```

```css
ul.sublist {
 user-select: none;
 -o-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

ul.sublist,
ul.sublist ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
}

ul.sublist ul {
 margin-left: 12px;
 margin-top: 6px;
 margin-bottom: 6px;
 transition: .15s margin-top;
}

ul.sublist li {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

ul.sublist > li ul {
 display: none;
}

ul.sublist li.show > ul {
 display: block !important;
}

ul.sublist li > span > i {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 34px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 text-align: center;
 border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 font-style: normal;
 margin-left: 50px;
}

ul.sublist li > span,
ul.sublist li > a {
 position: relative;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.025);
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 8px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 min-width: 200px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
 transition: .15s padding-left, .15s background-color;
}

ul.sublist.counter li > span {
 padding-right: 43px;
}

ul.sublist li:last-child > span,
ul.sublist li:last-child > a {
 border-bottom: none;
}

ul.sublist li > span:hover,
ul.sublist li > a:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sublist counter">
 <li>
  <span>Гризли</span>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Взгляд гризли</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Отточенный клык</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Гризли программист</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <span>Для дома</span>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <span>Мебель</span>
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Жёлтый</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Попугай</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Ламинированный кот</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
    <span>Атмосфера</span>
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Бьющаяся</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Небьющаяся</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Инопланетная</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
    <span>Растения</span>
    <ul>
     <li>
      <span>Эволюционирующие</span>
      <ul>
       <li>
        <a href="#">Серьёзно?</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <span>Список</span>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <span>Длинный</span>
    <ul>
     <li>
      <span>Очень</span>
      <ul>
       <li>
        <span>Очень</span>
        <ul>
         <li>
          <span>Хотя</span>
          <ul>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Не очень</a>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <span>Услуги</span>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Кофе с печенками</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Похвалить код</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <span>Классика</span>
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Починка утюга</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <span>Животные</span>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Hello world!</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Твой код</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Педаль велосипеда</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <span>Электроника</span>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Без комментариев</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Скрыть счётчик можно удалением класса `counter`

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT `id`, `parent_id`, `name` FROM `category`"); 
$cats = array();
while($cat =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $cats[$cat['parent_id']][] =  $cat;
function create_tree ($cats,$parent_id){
    if(is_array($cats) and  isset($cats[$parent_id])){
        $tree = !$parent_id?'':'<ul>';
        foreach($cats[$parent_id] as $cat){
           $tree .= "<li>";
           $tree .= !isset($cats[$cat['id']])?"<a href='view_cat.php?cat=".$cat['id']."'>".$cat['name']."</a>":"<span>".$cat['name']."</span>";
           $tree .=  create_tree($cats,$cat['id']);
           $tree .= '</li>';         
        }
        $tree .= !$parent_id?'':'</ul>';
    }else return null;          
return !$parent_id?'<ul class="sublist counter">'.$tree.'</ul>':$tree;        
} 
echo create_tree($cats, 0);
```

Comment: посмотрел ваш пример да то что надо. А не могли бы с моим кодом соединить??. Что то у меня не получается.

Comment: @Евгений для решения другой проблемы создайте новый вопрос дабы сохранить пару вопрос-ответ. 

Не забудьте принять ответ выше, если он решает вашу проблему.

Comment: прошу прощения, у меня как раз написано как настроить стили для этого скрипта(который вверху я написал, думаю не стоит по новой вопрос писать как ваш и мой скрипт объединить:)

Comment: с начало недопонял логику кода, вы правы. внесу правки в ответ.

Comment: @Евгений внёс в ответ

Comment: спасибо вам большое) Дай бог вам здоровья:)